# Dynamically created list items draggable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, draggable

I am dynamically populating a list of senators, separated by political affiliation. That part works. I need to make each list item draggable. I can't get that to work.

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById(name).setAttribute('draggable');
```

in my list population loop, but I really don't know if that's the right way.

```
senatorList.forEach(({name, party}) => {
    let itemEl = document.createElement('li');
    itemEl.textContent = name;
    let listId = party === 'Democrat' ? '#democrats' : '#republicans';
    let listEl = document.querySelector(listId);
    document.getElementById(name).setAttribute('draggable');
    listEl.appendChild(itemEl);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains a couple of errors:

1. `setAttribute` requires **two** arguments: `attribute` and `value`.
2. You called `document.getElementById(name)` before adding `itemEl` to the document.

If I understood your intentions correctly, the code should look similar to this:

```js
const senatorList = [{
    name: 'senator1',
    party: 'Democrat'
  },
  {
    name: 'senator2',
    party: 'Democrat'
  },
  {
    name: 'senator3',
    party: 'Republican'
  },
];

senatorList.forEach(({
  name,
  party
}) => {
  let itemEl = document.createElement('li');
  itemEl.textContent = name;
  let listId = party === 'Democrat' ? '#democrats' : '#republicans';
  let listEl = document.querySelector(listId);
  itemEl.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
  listEl.appendChild(itemEl);
});
```

```html
<div id="democrats"></div>
<div id="republicans"></div>
```

Comment: OOOooohh. ok. Thank you.